# JS AJAX cache response

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching

So, I have following ajax function:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : custom.ajax_url,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        action : a,
        id : b,
        extra : d
    },
    success : c
  });
```

The data response is structured as following:

[image]

I want to cache the response.

How would I cache it and how do I control the cached data? (ie, accessing them, deleting, adding new response etc).

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe store it in local storage/cookies then update/delete/etc ?